# Why can't I add an int member to my GLSL shader input/output block?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm getting an "invalid operation" error when attempting to call `glUseProgram` against the fragment shader below. The error only occurs when I try to add an `int` member to the block definition. Note that I am keeping the block definition the same in both the vertex and fragment shaders. I don't even have to access it! Merely adding that field to the vertex and fragment shader copies of the block definition cause the program to fail.

```
#version 450

...

in VSOutput // and of course "out" in the vertex shader
{
    vec4 color;
    vec4 normal;
    vec2 texCoord;
    //int foo; // uncommenting this line causes "invalid operation"
} vs_output;
```

I also get the same issue when trying to use free standing in/out variables of the same type, though in those cases, I only get the issue if accessing those variables directly; if I ignore them, I assume the compiler optimizes them away and thus error doesn't occur. It's almost like I'm only allowed to pass around vectors and matrices...

What am I missing here? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation that would indicate that this should be an issue.

**EDIT**: padding it out with  `float[2]` to force the int member onto the next 16-byte boundary did not work either.

**EDIT**: solved, as per the answer below. Turns out I could have figured this out much more quickly if I'd checked the shader program's info log. Here's my code to do that:

```
bool checkProgramLinkStatus(GLuint programId)
{
    auto log = logger("Shaders");

    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_TRUE)
    {
        log << "Program link successful." << endlog;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool checkProgramInfoLog(GLuint programId)
{
    auto log = logger("Shaders");

    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar* strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
    if(infoLogLength == 0)
    {
        log << "No error message was provided" << endlog;
    }
    else
    {
        log << "Program link error: " << std::string(strInfoLog) << endlog;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I meant 16-byte boundary. I'll edit that...

Comment: No, the log is completely blank. The vertex and fragment shaders compile, both without errors, and without any output to the log. The error is only encountered on the `glUseProgram` call, and then that is only the extremely unhelpful "invalid operation" error. The log is blank at all times.

Comment: @NathanRidley: integer types cannot be interpolated by the GL and have always to be qualified as `flat` when they are to be used as input to the fragment shader (and of course also on the output side of the previous stage).

Comment: @derhass thanks! that was exactly the right answer, and solved the problem. if you add it as an answer, i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @NathanRidley: I added an answer. As a side note: you probably got `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on the `glUseProgram` because the program failed to link (or even to compile). You should check the info logs, it might have given a hint of the problem.

Comment: Yep, see the fourth comment in this thread.

Comment: @NathanRidley: well, I read that just as the _shader_'s compile info log, not the _program_'s link info log. This might be a link error error solely. In any case, the logs are not mandatory, but the compile and link status of the shader/program is, and you should definitively check both.

Comment: @derhass ah, thanks I didn't realise that the log types were distinct from each other. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(As already pointed out in the comments): The GL will never interpolate integer types. To quote the [GLSL spec (Version 4.5)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) section 4.3.4 "input variables":

> Fragment shader inputs that are signed or unsigned integers, integer vectors, or any double-precision
>   floating-point type must be qualified with the interpolation qualifier **`flat`**.

This of couse also applies to the corresponding outputs in the previous stage.